# uninitialized constant Object::Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule my jobs using [clockwork gem](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork). I have required a file using

```
 require "#{Rails.root}/path/to/some/file"
```

I get

```
 uninitialized constant Object::Rails
```

error. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to load rails

```
require File.expand_path("./config/environment", __FILE__)
```